# TFS database growing with builds

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We have a TFS 2013 server providing source control and build services. We recently turned on automated builds for our projects and we are finding that the database is growing very quickly with each build.

I understand that this version of TFS has added the option to output builds to the TFS server, in an un-version controlled location (http://nakedalm.com/new-un-versioned-repository-in-tfs-2012/)

We are only keeping the last two succesful builds, but it seems when we delete old builds we don't actually recover any space. I've been looking into it and it seems there is a destroy command I can use to delete old builds from the database, but I cannot find anything that mentions this injunction with the new TFS drop location.

Our builds were also applying labels, but I'm not sure if labels actually require any space, and whether that space is reclaimed after you delete an old label?

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labels do not consume any significant space.

> I understand that this version of TFS has added the option to output
>   builds to the TFS server, in an un-version controlled location
>   (http://nakedalm.com/new-un-versioned-repository-in-tfs-2012/)

This came from VSOnline, where your output could be stored back into source control, this is an available option in TFS2013 but only if you choose the Copy Build Ouput to Server option in the build defaults. Use a network share instead to store your build outputs, if you believe this is consuming too much space.

When you delete a build through the retention policy, most artefacts of the build will be deleted for example the drop folder, and you will no longer be able to see the build in the build screen, however this is only a logical delete and the records remain in the database but are flagged with a delete flag.

The Destroy command will physically delete the build from the system, it will be completely gone and all records will be removed from the DB, please bear in mind that TFS may not recover the space straight away, the TFSJob Agent will recover the space during its normal running process so you may not see the space recovered for 24 hrs +.

You can check the size of the test attachments table as you may find that your space is being consumed by test libraries etc that are being stored.

installing TFS Power tools will install the test attachement cleaner tool and running this will show you whether it is the test attachments that are consuming space. it has instructions for how to clean up the table and how to run a scheduled job to keep on top of the housekeeping

> TFSBUILD Destroy example
>   this will destroy all builds between 5/5/14 and 20/5/14 that have been deleted

```
tfsbuild destroy /collection:http://TFSServer:8080/tfs/TPC /dateRange:05/05/2014~20/05/2014 /buildDefinition:POC\zzz_DBSample
Microsoft (R) TfsBuild Version 12.0.0.0
for Microsoft Visual Studio v12.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Destroy build record for DEV_DBSample_1.0.14128.1 permanently? (Yes/No/All) y
Destroying DEV_DBSample_1.0.14128.1... Done
Destroy build record for DEV_DBSample_1.0.14128.2 permanently? (Yes/No/All) a
Destroying DEV_DBSample_1.0.14128.2... Done
Destroying DEV_DBSample_1.0.14128.3... Done
Destroying DEV_DBSample_1.0.14128.4... Done
Destroying DEV_DBSample_1.0.14128.5... Done
Destroying DEV_DBSample_1.0.14129.1... Done
Destroying DEV_DBSample_1.0.14129.2... Done
Destroying DEV_DBSample_1.0.14129.3... Done
Destroying DEV_DBSample_1.0.14134.1... Done
Destroying DEV_DBSample_1.0.14134.2... Done
Destroying DEV_DBSample_1.0.14135.1... Done
Destroying DEV_DBSample_1.0.14135.2... Done
```

note how the build definition name has changed since the builds were created and TFS still finds the correct records

Comment: Thank you, do you have any advice on how to perform a destroy of the build outputs? I can see documentation on the destroy command however I do not know the path of the build outputs to destroy.

Comment: you should just need to supply the project\DefinitionName and it'll handle everything else